# Convert string to column type in postgres select query

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a string column named `revenue` and want to convert it as column type. Any help is appreciated!! Thanks in advance

```
select format('%s','revenue') from testing limit 1;
 format 
--------
 revenue
(1 row)
```

This one cannot find the column name since it is a string. It would be great if there is any way to convert the `string` to `column` type

```
select format('%s',revenue) from testing limit 1;
 format 
--------
 23328
(1 row)
```

This one works as expected

Comment: How are you planning on using it? It sounds like you are asking about dynamic SQL.

Comment: Yes! I have a function for this!